# Why don't we name children Yitro?

Tags: names, parashas-yisro, pentateuch-chumash, yisro--the-man

Yitro appears to be an overall positive character in the Torah. At least as much as Noah or Saul, yet I do not know of contemporary (or even ancient) Jews named Yitro. Why is that?

Comment: I know people named Chovav

Comment: Who's stopping you?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3252

Comment: I know a kid named Jethro - he was adopted and converted.

Comment: I converted and my name is Yitro Chayim :)

Comment: There are Jews who have secular names such as Esau, Ishmael (of Talmud fame) John, Matthew, Peter, etc. I think it may simply be because the name Jethro is not that popular. One web site says that the name ranks #333 in the USA http://www.babycenter.com/baby-names-jethro-2293.htm

Comment: Gid'on named his firstborn son Yeter which is another name for Yitro. (Shoftim 8:20)

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97752/170

Answer (score 12):

A possible reason why we do not name children Yisro.

Perhaps the reason we do not name Yisro is due to the fact that Yisro decides to return to Midian and ignores Moshe’s plea to remain with the Jewish people and help guide them into the Land of Israel. http://www.torah.org/learning/rabbiwein/5767/yisro.html

Comment: +1. I'd also add his second-guessing Hashem: "If He commands you to do this [appoint judges, as per his suggestion], you will be able to endure, but if He prevents you [from doing it], you will be unable to endure" ([Rashi to 18:23](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15563&p=2&showrashi=true)).

Comment: Plus his faith in Hashem was only in supporting the winner.