# Is Rami a legitimate Jewish name?

Tags: names

It seems like it is only used as a nickname for Avraham or Rakhamim, but can the name Rami be given to a Jewish male?

I've seen the name given to rabbis in the gemarah (Rami Bar Hama and Rami Bar Pappa). However, it's hard to find someone these days with that name.

Comment: What is a "legitimate Jewish name"?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3252

Comment: Related also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57623

Comment: a diminutive of Rachamim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rabbi Baruch Efrati](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/189302-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99) says that it is a fine Jewish name.

Comment: what do we know about rabbi efrati? Is his opinion generally accepted by mainstream orthodox jewery?

Comment: @AniYodea: Rabbi Baruch Efrati studied in Merkaz HaRav yeshiva in Jerusalem and is a Rabbi in Efrat as well as a prolific and much-read writer on Torah issues. He heads the "Derech Emunah" (Way of Torah) movement of Israeli Orthodox rabbis.