# Does the name Rami (רמי‎) have a meaning based in Judaism? If so, what is it?

Tags: history, words, names, talmud-gemara, rabbis

Does the name Rami (רמי‎), as used by figures in the Talmud such as Rami bar Papa and Rami bar Chama, have a meaning based in Judaism? If so, what is it?

If רמ means *high* or *exalted*, does רמי mean *my exalted*?

I am assuming that the name רמי is a full proper Jewish name and not a nickname for Rahamim or Yermiyahu.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31013/is-rami-a-legitimate-jewish-name

Comment: Resource check for us - The last paragraph seems to have been copied or paraphrased from Wikipedia. Is that where you got it from? It also states, there, that it is related to "Ram", meaning "exalted", as you surmised. However, as there is no source for that claim, I am not making this an answer. The notion sounds credible but unconfirmed.

Comment: @DanF, Your investigative skills are right on point. I also didn't find the full translation of the name in that article.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in modern Hebrew, Rami is most often a nickname for Avraham.

Answer (score 4):

רמי is actually short for  רב אמי

Source Pesachim 27b:
א"ר אמי בר חמא בשרשיפא בעא מיניה רמי בר חמא מרב חסדא תנור שהסיקו בעצי הקדש. This is confirmed in Sefer
[https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/תולדות_תנאים_ואמוראים/א/ר%27_אמי_בר_חמא](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90/%D7%A8%27_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%90)
I cannot find a source for the meaning of this name other than perhaps it's referring to a covenent of kehuna as translated in Targum Yonasan on Bamidbar 25,12 בִּשְׁבוּעָא אֵימַר לֵיהּ מִן שְׁמִי הָאֲנָא גָזַר לֵיהּ יַת קְיָמִי שְׁלַם. 
   The aromaic term for a covenant is מומי as it says in Nedarim 10b: מומי מומתא הרי אלו כינויין לשבועה

Rami or Rav Ami bar chama was a Cohen as clearly indicated in Rashi Shabbos 10b:
רב חסדא - כהן הוה כדאמרינן (ברכות פ"ו דף מד.) גבי עיר אחת היתה בא"י ובה שמונים זוגות אחים כהנים הנשואים שמונים זוגות אחיות כהנות ובדקו מסורא עד נהרדעא ולא אשכחו אלא תרתי בנתיה דרב חסדא דהוו נסיבי לרמי בר חמא ולמר עוקבא בר חמא:

Comment: How do you know that Chama didn’t have two children, one named Rav Ami and one named Rami?

Comment: @DonielF see https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/תולדות_תנאים_ואמוראים/א/ר%27_אמי_בר_חמא

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this claim:](http://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Rami)

> Rami is a form of the Hebrew and Indian name, Ram.

Regarding Ram, the same site says:

> From Hebrew roots, its meaning is 'exalted, supreme'. The name was
>   borne by the second son of Hezron, a descendant of Judah in the Old
>   Testament of the Bible.

Sure enough, Ram is mentioned in Ruth 4:19:

> וְחֶצְרוֹן֙ הוֹלִ֣יד אֶת־רָ֔ם וְרָ֖ם הוֹלִ֥יד אֶת־עַמִּֽינָדָֽב׃
>
> and Hezron begot Ram, and Ram begot Amminadab

It's possible that "Rami" was similar at that time to adding the "i" vowel sound to names then, as many do today such as *Shmuli*. *Avrami* and *Chani*, etc.

I am surmising that the Egyptian name for Paroah, *Ramses*, may have emanated from the same root name. Similar idea may apply to the famous "Romulans" from one of the old *Star Trek* episodes.

Comment: Thanks for finding the source in Ruth. Wouldn't your reasoning of adding the "i" vowel to names make the name more of a nickname and not an actual name?

Comment: @AniYodea It's hard to tell what might have been considered a nickname then as it is sometimes hard to tell, now. There's a M.Y. question regarding how to call people to the Torah using "nicknames". The answer, there, says, you use whatever name was assigned at your brit. So if they called someone "Rami" at the brit, which I assume is what they did, then it's no nickname. I can't say why they used that name or how common it was. Just be glad that they didn't name him "Ramio", as then his sister might have been named "Juliet" :-)

Comment: This claim is based on modern Hebrew but the gemorah indicates otherwise see my answer bellow