# Any famous Jews named Muhammad, Mahmud, Mehmet, etc.?

Tags: halacha, history, names, islam

There is a halacha that one may not name a child after an evildoer, a principle known as *shem reshaim yirkav* taken from [Yoma 38b](http://e-daf.com/?ID=1000) ("ועל בן קמצר וחביריו נאמר ושם רשעים ירקב", cf. [Mishlei 10:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%99_%D7%96)). Later authorities discuss the parameters of this halacha, of which you may see a summary [here](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/halachah/sn-hl-104.htm).

Now, occasionally there have been seeming exceptions to this rule, most famously ר' ישמעאל of the Talmud. A handful of other Jews have also been named ישמעאל -- including fairly recently (e.g. the late 18th century Rabbi Laudadio Sacerdote of Italy, whose Italian name is a calque of the Hebrew ר' ישמעאל כהן). There are [various halachic justifications](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/halachah/sn-hl-104.htm) for the use of this name, but the very fact that it was used is assumed to be evidence that it is permissible (though not ever a popular choice among Jews).

The names *Muhammad*, *Mahmud*, *Mehmet*, and various similar names are extremely common throughout the Muslim world. Are there any examples of these being used as names by Jewish figures? If so, it would provide interesting evidence for a few discussions, including whether the Muslim figure Muhammad is viewed as a *rasha*, and whether names that are etymologically related to the name of a *rasha* are also forbidden for use.

Comment: shamuel ban 3alee was a pseudo jo'on in boval during rambams time. ban 3alee meaning his father was 3alee which is an muslim character

Comment: @Mori was his father Jewish?

Comment: @DoubleAA most likely? i mean rabbeinu saa3dyo jo'ons name in arabic is saee3d. and im sure others had arabic name too

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/jewish-names-that-are-not-common/13706#comment23875_13706

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73

Comment: What about other gentile (or Christian) names?  I know several Jews named "Paul" or "Matthew" etc.

Comment: And why are we assuming Muhammad, Mahmud, Mehmet, etc, are all evil?  Granted, Muhammad has a mixed record regarding Jews, but... (BTW, "Mahmud" doesn't have anything to do with Muhammad.  It means "praise."  ע"ש Wikipeida.)

Comment: @Shmuel So does Muhammad. All these names have the same _shoresh_.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60280/5514

Comment: Yishmael did Teshuva towards the end of his life

Comment: Laudadio Sacerdote  is not Ishmael. laudare in Italian is to compliment, to praise, לשבח, להלל

Comment: correction to my post above, shamueil ban alee has been read this way by scholars until recently where people agree its eilee like eilee hakkohein

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: Pulitzer-winning David Mamet (with a very Jewy first name) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mamet

Comment: This does not show that the last name is derived from the Muslim name (which was the question).

Answer (score -1):

The most famous Jew with the name Mehemed was Shabbatai Tzvi upon his conversion to Islam. His full adopted name was then Aziz Mehemed Effendi.