Why do we have different names today than in ancient Judaism?
There are definitely exceptions, but for the most part, it seems that from the Beis Hamikdash period up until the era of the Rishonim, the traditional names we use today were relatively uncommon (such as those of the Avos/Shevatim/Moshe/Ahron etc…).
Those eras also had many names that apparently never stood the test of time, such as Tarfon/Yose/Papa/Abaye/Ravina/Ami/Asi and Ulah (not to mention the countless examples throughout Nach) etc.
Does anyone have any insight or historical sources that suggest a reason for the lack/falloff and just overall popularity of Jewish names in these eras and why they may or may not have survived till today?

The Avos names except for Avrohom were used, as were many of the Shevatim that are commonly used today (ie Shimon, Levi, Yehuda, Yosef, Binyamin). Many other traditional names we use today are also found throughout the Talmud.

The Gemara names mentioned are standard Aramaic names which were used by Christians in Persian Empire. Also some names are equivalent to Tanach names, Akiva - Yaakov, Yose - Yosef, Ezra - Azaria, Tarfon is from greek Τρύφων Tryphon literally "one who lives in luxury", Ulla - from aramaic one who came inside, etc.

See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/jewish-names-that-are-not-common.
